# Unable to make http request with Angular 2 rc5

Tags: angular, xmlhttprequest

I've just upgraded to `Angular 2 RC 5` and for a reason I can't figure out, I cannot make any http request (ie. the request is never made / doesn't show up in browser logs).

This is code that worked until today's upgrade.

```
console.log("Let's call github");
let url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/angular/angular/master/LICENSE';
return this.get(url).do(d=>console.log('success'));
```

When my component calls the function containing this code, `Let's call github` is output, but then the request is not made. I'm sure that `Observable` and `Http` from `@angular/http` are imported properly since this same code worked this morning.  My first thought was that I was missing the `HttpModule`, but I've confirmed that I import it into my main `AppModule`

In fact, if I comment out the `HttpModule` import, it makes no difference I can see. The error is the same, as follows:

```
Exception: TypeError: this._body is null
```

Here is an excerpt of the stack trace (at the bottom is the line calling the function quoted above):
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Update 2016-08-12

This has been addressed and will probably be fixed in the next release. A current workaround is to skip the `content-type` setting on `GET` requests, or to explicitly set `body=''` as a request option.

Link: [Gihub discussion](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10612)

## Original answer

The error seems to be with a block of code in a function I run before each http request.  Because the API I interact with expects `JSON` content, I have the following (`options` refers to the `RequestOptions` object used with every request):

```
//set content to JSON
if(!options.headers.has("Content-Type")){
    options.headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json")
}
```

If I comment out these lines, the request is made successfully. So I'm thinking that starting with `Angular 2 rc 5`, this block throws an error if the request body is empty (as is the case with my `get` request from the OP).

If my intuition is correct, this change in behavior is caused by [this commit](https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/83bc5c9) (new to `rc 5`)

> fix(http): convert objects passed to requests into a string

I bet that when I set the content-type header, Angular tries to be helpful and stringify the request body for me. Of course there is none with a `GET`, hence the error.